# How to conditionally style a row in a rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces

How can I change the style of a particular row based on a condition? I can use JSF EL in rich:column style class attribute, but I have to write for each column. I want to change the entire row.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do as you've already mentioned and put the style on the column.

However you could always try wrapping all of your columns in a `<rich:columnGroup>` which is supposed to output a `<tr>` and place your conditional style on that.

**EDIT:** (in response to comment): if the header facets in your columns are being broken then you can separate them into a column group as well. Should work - you may not even need the column group in the header??

Eg.

```
<rich:dataTable>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <rich:columnGroup>
      <rich:column>Header 1</rich:column>
      <rich:column>Header 1</rich:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
  </f:facet>
  <rich:columnGroup>
    <rich:column>Data</rich:column>
    <rich:column>Data</rich:column>
  </rich:columnGroup>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: Yes, This is a good solution, but unfortunately it breaks the header facet. Any ideas?

Comment: Already tried putting header in a column group, but richfaces skin is not applied. Any other ideas? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: As a side note, you can also hide columns this way by using redered.  <rich:columnGroup rendered="#{item.condition}">

Comment: This seemed like a perfect solution, then I find that `rich:columnGroup` doesn't have `class` or `style` attributes.

Comment: But it has a styleClass attribute

Answer (score 31):

Specifically for each column:

```
<rich:column styleClass="#{someBean.isSomething ? 'styleIfTrue' : 'styleIfFalse' }">
```

Comment: Good answer.  What's even better is to combine this suggestion with the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/967401/543738), then the style could be applied once to each row.

Answer (score 3):

This is my code, there is a checkbox on each row, if a checkbox is selected, the row is highlighted:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.approvalsResults}" var="approvals" styleClass="wp100 mtb20"  sortMode="single" id="approvalsTable"  
            enableContextMenu="false" selectionMode="none" reRender="actions" rows="10">

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="5%" sortBy="#{approvals.documentType}" sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.documentTypeSort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.documentType']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText  value="#{messages[approvals.documentType]}" id="col1"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="5%" sortBy="#{approvals.documentID}" sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.documentIDSort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.documentID']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{approvals.documentID}" id="col2"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="10%" sortBy="#{approvals.dateSubmitted}" sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.dateSubmittedSort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.dateSubmitted']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{approvals.dateSubmitted}" id="col3"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="15%" sortBy="#{approvals.submittedBy}" sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.submittedBySort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.submittedBy']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{approvals.submittedBy}"  id="col4"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="20%" sortBy="#{approvals.orgName}" sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.organizationSort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.userOrg']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{approvals.orgName}"  id="col5"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="5%" sortBy="#{approvals.value}" sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.valueSort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.value']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{approvals.value}"  id="col6"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="20%" sortBy="#{approvals.approverUserName}" sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.approverSort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.approver']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{approvals.approverUserName}" id="col7"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="15%" sortBy="#{approvals.dateAssigned}" sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.assignedSort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.assigned']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{approvals.dateAssigned}"  id="col8"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}" width="5%" sortBy="#{approvals.dateOutstanding}"  sortOrder="#{manageOutstandingApprovals.numOutstandingSort}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.daysOutstanding']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:outputText value="#{approvals.dateOutstanding}"  id="col9"/>
        </rich:column>

        <rich:column styleClass="#{approvals.rowcolor}">
          <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.selectButton']}" title="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.selectButtonTitle']}"/>
          </f:facet>
          <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="chkbx" value="#{approvals.selected}" id="selectBox" title="#{messages['outstandingApprovals.selectButtonTitle']}">
            <a:support event="onclick" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="approvalsTable" /> 
          </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </rich:column>
      </rich:dataTable>
```

In my backing bean:

```
public String getRowcolor() {
    if (selected) // selected is a variable whose value is from the checkBox  
        return "row-highlight-color"; // css id
    else
        return "row-white-color"; // css id
    }
```

Comment: I don't like this much because if the table cells have space between them, the background color may show through.  Also, as another user mentioned in a different thread, it's a lot of clutter in the bean to have display-specific logic.  It would be better to remove `getRowcolor()` and use the ternary operator in the page:
`styleClass="#{approvals.selected == true ? 'row-highlight-color' : 'row-white-color' }"`

Answer (score 2):

Use *rowClasses* ...
You can set a nice zebra style for example, and set a particular color when your value is set to what you want :

Here an example where my value is a boolean. (rowkey is the index of each row, you have to set it as this  in rich:datatable :

> rowKeyVar="rowkey"
>
> rowClasses="#{myBean.is_validValue == false ? (rowkey mod 2 == 0 ?
> 'order-table-even-row' : 'order-table-odd-row') : 'found'}"

I set Found class style when ma value == true.

CSS:

```
.found
{
background-color: #FACC2E;
}   
.order-table-even-row
{
background-color: #FCFFFE;
}

.order-table-odd-row
{
background-color: #ECF3FE;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this kind of simple solution +1 for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dataTables columnClasses and rowClasses properties.

That way you can produce the result which is shown [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=usage&cid=1543478)

Comment: That won't allow you to set the style conditionally unless you put in as many class names as you have rows.

Comment: Ahh Im sorry he want conditional styling on every single row. I thought he wanted to place conditional formatting on all the rows, but didnt want to write the condition for all the columns

Answer (score 0):

I've done an hybrid solution with Javascript.

```
<rich:column styleClass="expired" rendered="#{documento.expired}">
<f:facet name="header">
Da evadere entro
</f:facet>                  
<h:outputText value="#{documento.timeAgoInWords}" />
</rich:column>
```

and then in Javascript (with Prototype which is included in Richfaces)

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  function colorize() {    
    $$('td.expired').each(function(el) {
      el.up().addClassName('expired');      
    });
  }

  Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    colorize();
  });
</script>
```

edit:

this add a conditional css class with rendered:

```
<rich:column styleClass="expired" rendered="#{documento.expired}">
```

with javascript I loop on every td with css class expired `$$('td.expired')` and add the same css class to the upper node tr with `el.up()`.

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {});
```

this simply runs the function when the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Seems interesting: could you explain it a little? 

I mean, I understand you put the 'scaduto' and 'expired' class to <td> element, but the requirements where to color the entire row.

I mean, since there's not condition on the column, how do you change the class based on a value on the bean? 

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I've edited the post, it's clear now? :) I can post full source code if you want.

Comment: Isn't that unnecessarily complex?  JavaScript isn't needed to solve the original question.

Answer (score 0):

When using h:datatable, create a bean method and call this to determine the style. Perhaps this could also be done for a rich:datatable?

`public String getStyleSelectedOrderRows() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] oddEven = new String[]{"oddRow,", "evenRow,"};
        int i = 0;
        for (MyObject object: myObjectList) {
            sb.append(object.isSelected() ? "selected," : oddEven[i++ % 2]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }`

and in the .xhtml:

`<h:dataTable rowClasses="#{bean.styleSelectedOrderRows}"`

Comment: It's better not to have display-specific code in the bean.  Use the ternary operator instead.  See my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963971/how-to-conditionally-style-a-row-in-a-richdatatable#comment21375851_11871439) in this thread.  Also, `h:datatable` already has hooks for odd/even row styling, right?